# pyspark - AFT Survival regression predicting infinity - cannot understand why

Tags: python, apache-spark, machine-learning, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying to replicate [this Kaggle solution](https://www.kaggle.com/ludobenistant/predictive-maintenance-1/notebook) by using pyspark.

[Data(56 kb)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6sRVJYbBzKVTFo0UjduNEhUTWdXY1pwMkJLbFRGQWcwYkR3/view): Sample

```
lifetime,broken,pressureInd,moistureInd,temperatureInd,team,provider
56,0,92.17885406,104.2302045,96.51715873,TeamA,Provider4
81,1,72.07593772,103.0657014,87.27106218,TeamC,Provider4
60,0,96.27225443,77.80137602,112.1961703,TeamA,Provider1
86,1,94.40646126,108.4936078,72.02537441,TeamC,Provider2
34,0,97.75289859,99.413492,103.7562706,TeamB,Provider1
```

The crux R code is:

```
# Choose the dependant variables to be used in the survival regression model.
dependantvars = Surv(maintenance$lifetime, maintenance$broken)

# Create model (use the gaussian method)
survreg = survreg(dependantvars~pressureInd+moistureInd+temperatureInd+team+provider, dist="gaussian",data=maintenance)
```

I ported this code to pyspark using [RFormula](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#rformula) as follows:

```
rawDF = spark.read.format("csv").option("header","true").option("inferSchema","true").load("data/maintenance_data.csv")
formula = RFormula(formula="lifetime ~ pressureInd + moistureInd + temperatureInd + team + provider")
output = formula.fit(rawDF).transform(rawDF)
final_df = output.select("label",col("broken").cast("double").alias("censor"),"features")
aft = AFTSurvivalRegression(quantileProbabilities=[0.1,0.7],quantilesCol="quantiles")
model = aft.fit(final_df)
model.transform(final_df).show(truncate=False)
```

Output:

```
+-----+------+---------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+
|label|censor|features                                                 |prediction|quantiles     |
+-----+------+---------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+
|56.0 |0.0   |(8,[0,1,2,4],[92.17885406,104.2302045,96.51715873,1.0])  |Infinity  |[NaN,Infinity]|
|81.0 |1.0   |(8,[0,1,2],[72.07593772,103.0657014,87.27106218])        |Infinity  |[NaN,Infinity]|
|60.0 |0.0   |[96.27225443,77.80137602,112.1961703,0.0,1.0,0.0,1.0,0.0]|Infinity  |[NaN,Infinity]|
```

Using `model.predict` against a single feature is also giving infinity.

Can you tell me what I am doing wrong? Why am I getting infinity as the prediction?

So far, the only difference I could find was pyspark's AFT survival regression uses Weibull distribution, where as R code in the kaggle uses Gaussian distribution.

Comment: The Weibull distribution will have a few parameters from the fit. Can you post the values that you get?

Comment: hI @AlexR what exactly do you want me to post from the model  , link to the AFTSurvivalRegression Model api https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.ml.html#pyspark.ml.regression.AFTSurvivalRegressionModel

Comment: Hi @AlexR. these are some basic parameters.                        
Coefficients: [4.51915325505,18.1934487291,4.76894841593,29.3062853569,27.7259698103,25.9894622866,25.2049578785,20.6356434316]
Intercept: 18.264918617684508
Scale: 7.115623787209041e+32

Comment: So clearly the scale is blowing up like crazy. Do you have any extreme outliers? What happens if say, you filter out the top 0.1% of times?

Comment: quantiles [0.25,0.5,0.75,0.99]  for "lifetime","broken","pressureInd","moistureInd","temperatureInd"      
                                                                                                           
 `[34.0, 60.0, 80.0, 93.0],
 [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0],
 [85.56227794, 97.30113122, 112.2564357, 146.48261],
 [92.77764496, 99.43773299, 106.1237704, 122.3492056],
 [87.67851893, 100.6230519, 113.8027764, 147.0523134]]`

Comment: Looks like censor value will be inverse of broken value. Isn't it ? That's why you are getting infinity prediction.